# Programmatically create simple drawable to be placed in ImageResource using SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am looking to see if there is a way to programmatically create an ImageResource (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/DeveloperToolsSupport/ImageResource).

For instance with a dynamic number written into it? It seems this was added very recently (MacOS 14.0+). I am using only SwiftUI in my project. It seems a drawable could be programmatically created and placed into a Bundle.

Comment: An `Image` can be created from drawing instructions, if that helps. See [init(size:label:opaque:colorMode:renderer:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image/init(size:label:opaque:colormode:renderer:))